# Converting SVG into arbitrarily sized image on iOS

Tags: ios, svg, core-graphics, vector-graphics

I have several SVG images that I would like to use in an iOS application, and, in short, I would like to turn the SVG images into `UIImages` (or `CGImages`).

My goal is that I should be able to load the images from the `.svg` files at an arbitrary size (assuming correct W/H ratio) and store them as `UIImages` or `CGImages` without any loss of image quality. (Note this all has to happen at runtime, pre-converting the images to various sized `.png` files and putting them in the App bundle isn't a viable option.)

Is this possible, and if so, how could I go about doing this? I have a good working knowledge of `Core Graphics` but I have never worked with vector graphics before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) could help you - this library renders SVGs onto `CALayer` instances; from that, you can easily composite the image to a bitmap and make a CGImage of it.

Comment: Can someone add some details about how to actually do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend converting a vectored document to a bitmap in most instances, but if you must [SVGgh](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh) has a class SVGRenderer which has a method -(UIImage*)asImageWithSize:(CGSize)maximumSize andScale:(CGFloat)scale which will create a UIImage.

This is assuming SVGgh renders your SVGs properly, it doesn't support image effects, for instance.

```
 #import <SVGgh/SVGgh.h>
-(UIImage) imageFromSVGURL:(NSURL*)svgURL withSize:(CGSize)maximumSize andScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    SVGRenderer* renderer = [[SVGRenderer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:svgURL];
    return [renderer asImageWithSize:maximumSize andScale:scale];
}
```